# Laravel - how to add error message without specific field

Tags: php, validation, laravel, eloquent

I'm new to Laravel and I'm struggling a bit with validation logic. I understand how to add custom errors using, e.g.,:

```
$model->errors()->add('field_name', 'error_code');
```

But sometimes a model needs to fail validation for reasons that aren't specific to any one field. For example, an accounting transaction might fail validation because it doesn't balance. That validation rule is based on an aggregate calculation, not any particular attribute.

Ideally you could do something like:

```
$model->errors()->add('_global', 'overarching_error');
```

But I'm pretty confident that's not the preferred approach. How should this be handled?

Many thanks.